# Direct and Inverse Mellin transform for a simple function do not fit

Tags: integral-transforms, mellin-transform

I have to find $\cal{M}(f)$ where $f(x)=x,\ 0<x<a$ and zero otherwise. Thus, we can write $f(x)=xH(a-x)$ where $H(x)$ is the unit Heaviside function. Then I obtained
$$
{\cal M}(f)(s)=F(s)=\int_0^a x^s \,\mathrm dx=\frac{a^{s+1}}{s+1},
$$
for $s>-1$. I decided to check the result by finding the inverse transform
$$
{\cal M}^{-1}(F)(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{a^{s+1}x^{-s}}{s+1}ds=x.\tag{1}
$$
The above result obtained using pole $s=-1$.
Thus, instead of $f(x)=xH(a-x)$ I obtained just $x$.

> Why is the result different?

Comment: Perhaps because you evaluated the residue of $\frac{a^{s+1}}{s+1}x^{-s}$ at $s=-1$ whereas the Mellin transform is only valid for $\Re(s)>-1$? I believe formula (1) for the inverse Mellin transform must be evaluated at $c>-1$.

Comment: @StevenClark Definitely, $c>-1$. But the integration goes to the left from $\Re s=c$. Then we integrate $\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^s$, which goes to infinity if $x>a$ and $s\to -\infty$. May be a residue at $-\infty$ should be counted anyhow?

Comment: The integration does not go to the left from $R(s)=c$, rather it is along the vertical line $s=c+i\,t$. The simplest case would be $c=0$: $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int\limits_{-i\,\infty}^{i\,\infty}\frac{a^{s+1}}{s+1}\,x^{-s}\,ds$. I believe the substitution $s=i\, t$ leads to $\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a^{1+i \,t}}{1+i\,t}\,x^{-i\,t}\,dt$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the integral over $t$ can be evaluated, but I believe Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha both give the correct answer for the inverse Mellin transform (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+mellin+transform+a%5E%28s%2B1%29%2F%28s%2B1%29).

Comment: I am trying to figure out the result analytically using residue but fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\frac{a}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-i\infty }^{c+i\infty }{\frac{1}{s+1}{{\left( \frac{a}{x} \right)}^{s}}ds}=\frac{a}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-i\infty }^{c+i\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{s\log \left( a/x \right)}}}{s+1}ds}$$
Where $c\gt-1$.  Now consider a semi-circular contour of radius $R>0$ joining the vertical line, closing it in a loop.  We have $s=R\cos \left( \theta  \right)+iR\sin \left( \theta  \right)$ in the exponential.  A circle in the RHP will mean $\cos \left( \theta  \right)\ge 0$ while one in the LHP yields $\cos \left( \theta  \right)\le 0$.  We want the integral to go to zero on this contour as $R$ becomes infinite and so we need a negative argument against $R$ in the exponential.  So for $0<a/x<1$ we close to the right, and so we don’t pick up the residue.  While for $a/x>1$ we close to the left and since $c>-1$ we pick up the residue.  Hence we retrieve your step function.

Comment: Thanks to @mathstackuser12, I did the following: 
(1) consider located in the left half-plane semicircle with vertical diameter $[-iR,iR]$ centered at origin;
(2) as mathstackused12 explained, the integration along the circular arc goes at $x<a$ to zero;
(3) integration along the diameter yields exactly $x$, same as the residue at $s=-1$;
(4) if $x>a$, then the integration along the half-circle arc goes to infinity as $R\to\infty$;
(5) if $x>a$, then integration along the diameter yields
$$ \frac{a}{2\pi }\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{-y+i} e^{iy\ln(a/x)}dy\to 0$$
as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: Thus, combining steps (4) and (5) above, we obtain infinity during integration along the semicircle. However, the result must be zero for $x>a$. I still could not figure out why didn't I get zero. Thank you.

Comment: @pabodu because the integral blows up over the semi-circle, you need to discard it and close in the other half plane.  That is you will need two different semi-circles, one closing in the LHP and one closing the RHP depending on the magnitude of x.

Comment: @pabodu If $x > a$, the integral over a left semicircle tends to a finite non-zero limit (equal to $2 \pi i$ times the residue of the integrand at $s = -1$).